# How to get which button clicking using Tag

Tags: ios, tags, uibutton

I created more than one button using tag++. I need to know which button clicking with sender method. When clicking button with tag i need to get values from database. shall i use if method for tag position for click button

```
button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(click1:)                                    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
     [button1 setTitle:@"click" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

     button1.frame = CGRectMake(xff, yff, 30.0, 20.0);

    int gTag = 1;                                    

      button1.tag = gTag;
       gTag++;

    [wbCont.scrollView  addSubview:button1];
```

Here i need to know button click:

```
 -(void)click1:(id)sender{


UIButton *button3=(UIButton *)sender;
switch([button3 tag]){
        //Do the switch case here

        NSArray *coorpaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *coordocumentsDirectory = [coorpaths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"docs dir is %@", coordocumentsDirectory);

        NSString *coorpath = [coordocumentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ohs.sqlite"];
        NSLog(@"filepath %@",coorpath);

        if (sqlite3_open([coorpath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {


            const char *sql =  [[NSString stringWithFormat:
                                 @"SELECT xcoor,ycoor,artt_id FROM touch where artt_id = %@", artID]cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


            NSLog(@"getmainsql is %s",sql);

            sqlite3_stmt *statement;

            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
                // We "step" through the results - once for each row.
                while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {



                    xff1=sqlite3_column_double(statement, 0);

                    yff1=sqlite3_column_double(statement, 1);

                    art_Id2 = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 2);

                    NSLog(@"xff1 is %f",xff1);

                    NSLog(@"yff1 is %f",yff1);

                    //  NSLog(@"zc is %@",zc);

                    NSLog(@"art_Id is %ld",(long)art_Id2);


                }

            }

        }


}
```

Comment: see my answer .You have the button instance in tht method ,youcan do anything from there,first typecast then only u ll get the correct tag value

Comment: @staticVoidMan :Updated the answer, Question was like that earlier So given answer like that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow.Please put the complete queston,You can edit the question ,but that shouldn't completely change the context of the question so that the answers looks completely different from what asked.Have some doubts?Look for more then only put a new question.Please read the #FAQ

Comment: as per the current edit, the switch case will not execute because there aren't any 'cases' specified. refer: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/The_Objective-C_switch_Statement

Comment: also, in which scenario is the tag being used? even if (somehow) the switch case worked, all tags will execute the same block of code. what's going on guys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sender returnes the object which performed the action.Typecast first the sender to button ,You can have all the properties achievable from tht object

```
-(void)click1:(id)sender{
    UIButton *button=(UIButton *)sender;
    switch([button tag]){
    //Do the switch case here
    }
}
```

So in your case

```
 -(void)click1:(id)sender{

        UIButton *button=(UIButton *)sender;
NSInteger tag = [button tag];
if( tag){
 NSArray *coorpaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *coordocumentsDirectory = [coorpaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"docs dir is %@", coordocumentsDirectory);
    NSString *coorpath = [coordocumentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ohs.sqlite"];
    NSLog(@"filepath %@",coorpath);
    if (sqlite3_open([coorpath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        const char *sql =  [[NSString stringWithFormat:
                             @"SELECT xcoor,ycoor,artt_id FROM touch where artt_id = %@", artID]cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"getmainsql is %s",sql);
        sqlite3_stmt *statement;
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            // We "step" through the results - once for each row.
            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                xff1=sqlite3_column_double(statement, 0);
                yff1=sqlite3_column_double(statement, 1);
                art_Id2 = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 2);
                NSLog(@"xff1 is %f",xff1);
                NSLog(@"yff1 is %f",yff1);
                //  NSLog(@"zc is %@",zc);
                NSLog(@"art_Id is %ld",(long)art_Id2);
    }
   }
 }
}
```

UPDATE

Yes you can use it

Note

use  `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` for achieving click event of button

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(click1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: Can you come to chat?

Answer (score 2):

it's easy just do this

```
-(void)click1:(id)sender{
    int tag = [sender tag];
    switch(tag){
    //Do the switch case here
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting some values from database. Can you check my edited code